# How can I see which POm dependency entry is adding a certain jar to eclipse classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is it possible using the m2e maven plugin for eclipse (or some other easy way), to figure out which `<dependency>` entry in my POM is the reason for a given .jar to be added to the classpath. afaik right click only allows me to see the pom of the given artifact.

[image: Eclipse example]

in this example the my pom looks like

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.medsea.mimeutil</groupId>
        <artifactId>mime-util</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

so it's pretty easy to understand that who is responsible for adding the log4j things

Comment: Are you talking about some dependency that happens to be in your classpath but is not listed on the screenshot?

Comment: no im thinking of dependencies listed in the screenshot, but not nes listed directly as <dependency> in my pom (meaning they are dependency of some POM my POM depends on)

Comment: I don't work with Eclipse thus cannot tell you if it has something to help you with this task, but you could use dependency plugin, specifically [build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) and [tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) goals from command line for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the POM in the m2e POM editor (should happen by default), click Dependency Hierarchy, type the name of the offending dependency into the filter box. It will highlight the dependency that drags it in.

Comment: awesome, completely missed this tab.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well figured it ..
right click->maven->exclude maven artifact would place a nice exclusion element on the dependency causing the inclusion

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.medsea.mimeutil</groupId>
        <artifactId>mime-util</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```